# Selenium java new ChromeDriver() не переключает на iframe

Tags: java, selenium, chromedriver

Здравствуйте дороги коллеги, есть сложность то ли с жизнью то ли с кодом )))
Selenium java new ChromeDriver() не переключает на iframe, пробовал switchTo() по id и name, пробовал с ожиданием. Заранее спасибо за ваши мнения и мысли, любая информация зайдет, гуглю сижу 4-час.

ChromeDriver version - 89.0.4389.23
Selenium version - 3.141.59

code:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 2, 100);
    webDriver.get("https://awmproxy.com/freeproxy.php");

    WebElement iframe = webDriverWait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                    By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?')]")));
    webDriver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rc-anchor-container']"));
    System.out.println(element.getText());
```

exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='rc-anchor-container']"}
```

Comment: Сергей, столкнулся с той же ситуацией, пока не победил. Возможно вопрос в структуре фреймов, вложенности и т.д. Если победили - поделитесь решением.

Comment: Ваш код работает. Я не смог воспроизвести вашу ошибку у себя

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемые коллеги, решил проблему следующей строкой кода (2-я в коде ниже), полное его объяснение, к сожалению привести не могу. При этом, мне достаточно было единоразово запустить программу с этой строкой, после чего в ней не было необходимости. Пожалуйста, обьясните с чем связано. Спасибо :-)

code:

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation", "load-extension"});
 WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```